# UILabel height not changing

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel, frame

I am trying to change my two labels heights defined in custom cell but failed many times. Height of labels should change with length of text populated in. I have successfully implemented the cell height in `heightForRowAtIndexPAth`but label height is not adjusting according to cell height. It either truncate the text or shrink the font. `SetNumberOfLines` to zero seems to have no effect. `ContentTextView` and `TransView` are my two `uiLabels`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Customcell";

    CustomeCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier   forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *text = [_detailItem objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    NSString *text2 = [_detailItem2 objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];


    CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(296.f, FLT_MAX);
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text];
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString2 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text2];

    CGRect rect = [attributedString boundingRectWithSize:maxSize
                                 options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                 context:nil];
    CGRect rect2 = [attributedString2 boundingRectWithSize:maxSize
                                                          options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                 context:nil];


    CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(500,CGFLOAT_MAX);
    CGSize requiredSize = [cell.contentTextView sizeThatFits:maximumLabelSize];
    CGSize requiredSize2 = [cell.transView sizeThatFits:maximumLabelSize];
    CGRect labelFrame = cell.contentTextView.frame;
    CGRect labelFrame2 = cell.transView.frame;
    labelFrame.size.height = requiredSize.height;
    labelFrame2.size.height=requiredSize2.height;
    cell.contentTextView.frame = labelFrame;
    cell.transView.frame=labelFrame2;
    [attributedString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:style range:NSMakeRange(0, [text length])];
    [attributedString2 addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:style range:NSMakeRange(0, [text2 length])];

    [cell.contentTextView setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    [cell.contentTextView setMinimumScaleFactor:FONT_SIZE];
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    [style setLineSpacing:2];
    [style setAlignment:(NSTextAlignment)kCTRightTextAlignment];
    [cell.contentTextView setNumberOfLines:0];
    [ cell.transView setNumberOfLines:0];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
    tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.576 green:0.796 blue:0.008 alpha:1];

    cell.contentTextView.attributedText = attributedString;
    cell.transView.attributedText=attributedString2;

    return cell;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by setting `constraints` on story board. In my case, i had calculate the cell height but my labels height were not adjusting accordingly. I follow the following steps.

1- On story board, click on 'Pin' appeared on bottom and set constraints (click on labels turn by turn).

2- In size inspector, change the intrinsic size of each label to "place holder".

3- Make sure to fix all warnings after you set your constraints otherwise it won't work

Answer (score 1):

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString * cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell==nil) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        UILabel *lblText = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 10, 275, [self dynamicHeightAtIndexPath:indexPath])];
        lblText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [lblText setTag:1];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lblText];
     }
     UILabel *lbl = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
     lbl.numberOfLines=0;
     lbl.attributedText = @"label text";
     return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

     return [self dynamicHeightAtIndexPath:indexPath]+20;

}

-(CGFloat)dynamicHeightAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(275, 9999);
    UIFont *myFont =[UIFont fontWithName:@"Halvetica" size:12]; //your font for label
    CGSize stringsize = [[self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] sizeWithFont:myFont
                                                         constrainedToSize:maximumSize
                                                             lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    return stringsize.height;
}
```

Comment: i have already initialised my labels in custom class. cell=nil statement won't work for me